# Why to use casting to instantiate views in android

Tags: android, view, casting

Does anyone know the reason to cast when instantiating a view?

e.g.: `TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);`

Comment: `findViewById()` does not instantiate a view.

Comment: Because findViewById() returns a view and that view could be any view.

Comment: I hate to see when great questions on SO get downvoted, but incorrect answers to these questions get highly upvoted. I do understand that the question seems trivial, but why downvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because all views in android are subclasses of [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class and [findViewById](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) does not know anything about the subclass, for instance you might have your own custom view. There is no way android would want to know about your view class, hence it just returns the superclass and you would have to manually typecast it to more specific implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for casting is because return type of `findViewById()` function in Android is `View`.

However, contrary to what @Bajji stated in his (currently accepted) answer, a function does have a mean to know about the type of `View` you are expecting to get and perform automatic casting to that class. Unfortunately, Android does not leverage this functionality...

The following function does that:

```
protected <T extends View> T findViewById(@IdRes int id) {
    return (T) getRootView().findViewById(id);
}
```

If you would have this function defined, then you could do it this way:

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

You can get a bit more info in this [blog post](http://www.techyourchance.com/casting-android-views/).